# How to call a function on onClick event in ReacJs

Tags: reactjs

I have `handleClick` event which by clicking `renderDetail` function must be run in `{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}` div.I do it like below code :

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  data: [],
  ShowInfo: {},
  text: {}

 }
}
render() {
const { data } = this.state
const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div class="item">
      <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
        <span>Click</span>
      </div>
      <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>
</div>
  )
})
return <div>{renderInfo}</div>
}

handleClick = (e, element, i) => {
  fetch('/json.bc', {
  method: 'POST',
  },)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
 let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
 this.setState(prevState => ({
 ShowInfo: { ...prevState.ShowInfo,[i]: this.renderDetail(Maindata, i)},
}))
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
}

renderDetail(element, i) {
 let lenfamilies = element.families.length
 let indents = []
let index = 0
for (let j = 0; j < lenfamilies; j++) {
  let numF = i
  let numS = j
  let stingF = numF.toString()
  let stingS = numS.toString()
  index = stingF + stingS
  indents.push(
  <div>
    <span
        key={index}
        onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)}
      >
        Click
      </span>
      <span key={index}>
        {this.state.text[index]}
      </span>
</div>
  )
}
 return(
       indents
       )
  }
  handleText = (e, element, index) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
        text: { ...prevState.text, [index]: "test" }////In this part   'test' should be set in  span but it is not been set
  }))
 }
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"))
```

Have you any other way to call `renderDetail` function in `handleClick` event?

Comment: Can you describe your issue? Do you get any error?

Comment: HI @barbsan.Yes I have a problem. Could you look at my edited code?

Comment: The main problem is by clicking `onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)}` the text of `<span  key={index}>{this.state.text[index]}</span>`  should be test and test is going to be dynamic. I put test just as testing, but it is not been set

Answer (score 0):

You could use callback

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      ShowInfo: {},

     }
    }
    render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div class="item">
          <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
            <span>Click</span>
          </div>
          <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return <div>{renderInfo}</div>
    }

    handleClick = (e, element, i) => {
      fetch('/json.bc', {
      method: 'POST',
      },)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
     let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
     this.setState(prevState => ({
     ShowInfo: { ...prevState.ShowInfo,[i]: (Maindata,i)=>{
     let element = Maindata
     let lenfamilies = element.families.length
     let indents = []
    let index = 0
    for (let j = 0; j < lenfamilies; j++) {
      let numF = i
      let numS = j
      let stingF = numF.toString()
      let stingS = numS.toString()
      index = stingF + stingS
      indents.push(
        <div>
          <span
            key={index}>    
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    }
     return(
           indents
           )
      }
    }},
    }))
    }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
     ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"))
```

Comment: Hi @Abdulla Thanseeh. I tried your code  as you can see the result of fetch request should be set in `renderDetails` function, but by using callback the result of fetch request wont be shown:| and there is no error in console.

Comment: `<div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>` is empty by using callback

Comment: I can see that the  `json.bc` is loaded  in network tab by result. When I wrote ` console.log(lenfamilies)` there would not be any result.

Comment: can you create a sandbox

Comment: I haven't created a sandbox up to now.

Comment: I will try to create the sandbox:|